# SAS SQL to aggregate rows

Tags: sql, sas

I am new to SAS and I am working with a large dataset to create a column with data from each group of id. A simplified form of my dataset looks like this:

ID Name

```
1 AAA   
1 AAA   
1 BBB   
2 CCC   
2 CCC   
2 AAA   
3 DDD
3 BBB
3 AAA
4 BBB
4 BBB
```

and the result I am looking for is:

ID Name         NEW_ID

```
1  AAA     AAA, BBB
1  AAA     AAA, BBB
1  BBB     AAA, BBB
2  CCC     CCC, AAA
2  CCC     CCC, AAA
2  AAA     CCC, AAA
3  DDD     DDD, BBB, AAA
3  BBB     DDD, BBB AAA
3  AAA     DDD, BBB, AAA
4  BBB     BBB
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Remember ID may not always come as a number. Thanks.

Comment: You can do this with a data step, but not easily with `proc sql`.

Comment: What's the database? sql server?

Comment: No. it is a sas dataset.

Comment: What database is HOLDING the data?

Comment: The dataset is not in a database. It is a sas dataset stored in a large network drive.

Comment: and I have a stand alone base sas

Comment: Oh one more thing. I know this can be done using transpose but I am trying to stay away from transposing a large dataset.

Comment: is the data set sorted by ID?

Comment: yes it is sorted by ID but remember ID can be a combination of characters and numbers.

Comment: if someone can show me a solution using a data step that would work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot think of a way to do this in a single data step.  But 2 is pretty easy.  First collect the values and then join them back to the main data set.

```
data first;
set have;
by id;
format COL $2000.;
retain COL;

if ^last.id then
   col = strip(col) || strip(name) || ",";
else do;
   col = strip(col) || strip(name);
   output;
end;
run;

data want;
merge have first;
by id;
run;
```